# C pre-processor error

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor, kernighan-and-ritchie

I expected the code to output suse.sys but it actually prints win.sys. Why is this the case?

```
 #define SYS SUSE

 #if SYS == WIN
   #define HDR "win.sys"
 #elif SYS == SUSE
   #define HDR "suse.sys"
 #else
   #define HDR "default.sys"
 #endif
 #include HDR
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
   char *name = HDR;
   printf("%s\n", name);
   return 0;
 }
```

This is similar to the example in the **C** Programming language second edition. The .sys files don't contain anything, they have no real use.

Comment: Are `HDR` and `SUSE` defined?

Comment: HDR gets defined in the if statement and SUSE does not get defined. SUSE is just the replacement text for the token SYS

Comment: What exactly is the output when you try to compile this? `SUSE` might not be defined at all... also: `char *name` should be `const char *name` (nitpick)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem The output is "win.sys", and for thanks for the tip for using const.

Comment: @CSStudent Yeah, I meant `WIN`, not `HDR` of course.

Comment: IS it possible that somehow `WIN == SUSE` ?

Comment: @CSStudent: try printing all of the macro's, `SYS`, `WIN` and `SUSE`, see if `WIN`'s value isn't the same as `SUSE`

Comment: The first `#if` is replaced to `#if SUSE == WIN`, `SUSE` and `WIN` are (I assume) not defined, so they default to 0 (because they are used in an arithmetic expression), so it is evaluated as `#if 0 == 0`, which is 1, so `HDR` is defined to `"suse.sys"`. You seem to want to compare strings by the preprocessor, which isn't possible.

Comment: @unwind This may be my problem. WIN isn't defined at all. I simply thought the if was checking SYS (SUSE) against the string after the ==. Is the if actually checking for a #define with that namee? (and then subsequently the value associated with the #define name).

Comment: @mafso Yes, that explains it. I didn't think about it comparing two #define'd names values. Thank you.

Comment: @CSStudent See mafso's comment, that pretty much nailed it.

Comment: @CSStudent, as mafso pointed out: comparing strings is not possible

Comment: So you could add two more defines: `#define WIN 0` and `#define SUSE 1` or something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preprocessor comparison with `==` works on integer values, not strings or names of macros. You should be able to fix this by first defining the macros `SUSE` and `WIN` with integer values, e.g.,

```
#define SUSE 1
#define WIN 2
#define SYS SUSE
```

After this both `SYS` and `SUSE` resolve to the integer 1, and the comparison should work.

However, I would suggest a more conventional approach of defining different macros altogether for the systems, e.g.:

```
#define SYS_SUSE
//#define SYS_WIN

#if defined(SYS_SUSE)
#define HDR "suse.sys"
#elif defined(SYS_WIN)
#define HDR "win.sys"
#else
#define HDR "default.sys"
#endif
```

This approach has the advantage of being able to more conveniently specify the system on command-line, makefiles, etc. without depending on the numeric constants being defined in every context:

```
cc -DSYS_WIN -c foo.c
```

Comment: +1 for giving both, a solution close to how OP tried it and a better approach to do the same (including reasoning why it is better).